# How to convert 2 dimensional arraylist to datatable?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, datatable

I need a function that returns a datatable, from any arraylist (2 dimensions) as arguments? Thanks for your help

Creating two dimensional Arraylist:

```
Public Overrides Function Find(Optional ByRef conditions As ArrayList = Nothing) As System.Collections.ArrayList
    Dim collection As New ArrayList
    Dim cmd ......... ' Select command based on an arraylist of conditions
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        Dim cnt As New contact
        cnt .Id() = dr("id")
        cnt .Name= dr("name")
        '.........  other columns are imported
        collection.Add(cnt )
    End While
    dr.Close()
    Return collection
End Function
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a datatable?

Comment: @ Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå, Yes I do :)

Comment: Do you know how to loop over a multidimensional array?

Comment: I would like to see how the "2 dimensional arraylist" is created

Comment: The obstacle that I have found is to create the columns of DataTable as collones found in the ArrayList.
Importing data lines its not a problem.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: @Plutonix : Creating to dimensional Arraylist
Public Overrides Function Find(Optional ByRef conditions As ArrayList = Nothing) As System.Collections.ArrayList
Dim collection As New ArrayList
....
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
....
            While dr.Read()
               Dim cnt As New contact

                cnt .Id() = dr("id")
                cnt .Name= dr("name")
...

               collection.Add(cnt )

            End While

            dr.Close()
  Return collection
End Function

Comment: That is just a simple ArrayList.  There is one item per element.  The fact that each element is an object with 2 properties does not make it 2 dimentional.  There are no "columns" in an ArrayList

Comment: @Plutonix: I want to understand your point of view.
SQL table data is imported and stored in the ArralList as 2 dimension table (columns and rows), how do you see that?

Comment: `collection.Add(cnt)` adds **one** new item to the ArrayList.  In this case it is a `Contact` object, but that is just one thing/Object.   The fact that `Contact` has 2 properties (which *were* DB columns) does not make the ArrayList multi-dimensional.  XY questions like these are why code and previous efforts in questions are important

Comment: If the source for this is a DB, why not just fill a DataTable with the results to start with?

Comment: @P This does indeed smell like an XY problem as OP should probably be using a data adapter instead of a data reader.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå It is true it is more convenient to use the DataTable directly, but I work on a project based on a DAO difinitions already created, they are defined in the same way (which return ArrayList), change  them all is a tiring work.

Comment: The ArrayList is suboptimal to start with.  NET has had typed collections like `List(Of T)` since NET 2.0 (2005).  I'm not sure you mean DAO either because things like `SqlDataReader` are NET data providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suitable solution found:**

```
Public Shared Function ArrayListToDataTable(ByVal arraylist1 As ArrayList) As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()

    For i As Integer = 0 To arraylist1.Count - 1
        Dim GenericObject As Object = arraylist1.Item(i)
        Dim NbrProp As Integer = GenericObject.GetType().GetProperties().Count

        For Each item As PropertyInfo In GenericObject.GetType().GetProperties()
            Try
                Dim column = New DataColumn()
                Dim ColName As String = item.Name.ToString

                column.ColumnName = ColName
                dt.Columns.Add(column)

            Catch

            End Try
        Next

        Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

        Dim j As Integer = 0
        For Each item As PropertyInfo In GenericObject.GetType().GetProperties()
            row(j) = item.GetValue(GenericObject, Nothing)
            j += 1
        Next

        dt.Rows.Add(row)

    Next
    Return dt

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 years, Let me answer this=>

```
Function ConvertArrayListToDataTable(ByVal arraylist As ArrayList) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        If arraylist.Count <= 0 Then
            Return dt
        End If

        Dim propertiesinfo As PropertyInfo() = arraylist(0).GetType().GetProperties()

        For Each pf As PropertyInfo In propertiesinfo
            Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn(pf.Name)
            dc.DataType = pf.PropertyType
            dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        Next

        For Each ar As Object In arraylist
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            Dim pf As PropertyInfo() = ar.GetType().GetProperties()

            For Each prop As PropertyInfo In pf
                dr(prop.Name) = prop.GetValue(ar, Nothing)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function
```